# Why do I get a 401 error when calling a WCF service from a web part?

Tags: authentication, wcf, kerberos

I have a SharePoint 2010 web part and WCF service deployed to a web application using Kerberos authentication. The service was developed based on the [walkthrough from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx) with the only difference that `ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows` so that Kerberos is used.

The web application is being reverse-published through ISA. However we've never had an issue with this before.

When the web part calls the service, a 401 error occurs with the following exception message:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme
>   'Negotiate'. The authentication header
>   received from the server was 'NTLM'.

I configured Fiddler on the web application running the web part and found that both Kerberos and NTLM authentication headers are being returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: 541e724c-85a7-47a0-b045-827e1c50793c
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oXsweaADCgEBoQsGCSqGSIL3EgECAqJlBGNgYQYJKoZIhvcSAQICAwB+UjBQoAMCAQWhAwIBHqQRGA8yMDEwMDkxNDA1MjY1NlqlBQIDDgespgMCASmpDBsKREVDUy5MT0NBTKoXMBWgAwIBAaEOMAwbCnNwX3dlYmFwcDE=
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.4762
Date: Tue, 14 Sep 2010 05:26:56 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

**Why then is the Kerberos authentication not accepted?** (As a side note, why is NTLM returned as well?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system admin only configured Kerberos for one web application. The web part was querying the WCF service for a different web application which only had NTLM configured.

<sub>(Sigh.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Is the web service on the same machine as SharePoint? If so, is it the ol' [loopback check problem](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/05/solution-for-being-unable-to-sign-in-to.html)?

Another common issue with WCF is that you must pass an identity (any, even fake ones) to get it past .net 3.5 sp1.

```
EndpointIdentity epi = EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("unknown");
EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(address), epi);
```

For a full sample see the `OpenService()` method on [this blog post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html).

Comment: It's not loopback check, and unfortunately the fake identity didn't make any difference.