# SharePoint 2010 Query service authentication problem

Tags: 2010, search, web-services, windows-authentication, kerberos

I am struggling with calling search.asmx service from asp.net page. I've created proxy class using svcutil.exe and run request using following code:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
binding.Security.Transport.Realm = string.Empty;
binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;
var service = new QueryServiceSoapClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://mysite/_vti_bin/search.asmx"));
service.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
var res = service.QueryEx(qXMLString);
```

Web application is set up using Kerberos authentication, I got exception

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'

in method *System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication*
I've tried set up *service.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;* but error is the same.

What can be the cause of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**UPD:**

I've tried above code to run in a console app, and all working fine, exception is thrown form asp.net codebehind only.

**UPD2:**

User which run this code has appropriate permissions in SharePoint (actually console app runs under the same user as codebehind).

Comment: Did you tried debugging it as to see if you are passing right credentials

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: AllowNtlm doesn't work anymore they got rid of it, need to allow this in your local policy instead.

Comment: Kai, I wrote solution and wondering if you have feedback on it? I am using Visual Studio to generate the proxy and then call the asmx service.

Answer (score 2):

Kai

I have done the solution but it's done the client in the Visual Studio 2012 using Service references. The solution is to make sure that you send a NTLM authentication request.

Here is the complete source code for a console application being done in Visual Studio 2012:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TestSearchASMX.SearchServiceRef;

namespace TestSearchASMX
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            QueryServiceSoapClient client = new QueryServiceSoapClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

            string query = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                             <QueryPacket xmlns=""urn:Microsoft.Search.Query"" Revision=""1000"">
                               <Query domain=""QDomain"">
                                  <SupportedFormats>
                                     <Format>
                                        urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document
                                     </Format>
                                  </SupportedFormats>
                                  <Context>
                                     <QueryText language=""en-US"" type=""STRING"">test</QueryText>
                                  </Context>
                               </Query>
                            </QueryPacket>";

            string result = client.Query(query.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

app.config will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="QueryServiceSoap">

                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
                </security>
              </binding>

           </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://skvkfm-100-1:46812/_vti_bin/search.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="QueryServiceSoap"
                contract="SearchServiceRef.QueryServiceSoap" name="QueryServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

If you're using Visual Studio 2008 then C# code will remain same but app.config will be slightly different to reflect the NTLM request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="QueryServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://skvkfm-100-1:46812/_vti_bin/search.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="QueryServiceSoap"
                contract="ServiceReference1.QueryServiceSoap" name="QueryServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

here is the outcome of my request:

```
<ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response"><Response domain="QDomain"><Range><StartAt>1</StartAt><Count>10</Count><TotalAvailable>100</TotalAvailable><Results><Document relevance="87307112" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"><Title>Test blogg</Title><Action><LinkUrl size="85948">http://skvkfm-100-1:9899/sites/sitedirectory/UB_bloggtest</LinkUrl></Action><Description /><Date>2013-01-09T18:20:56</Date></Document><Document relevance="86917136" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"><Title>test</Title><Action><LinkUrl size="0" fileExt="aspx">http://skvkfm-100-1:9899/sites/df/Lists/test/AllItems.aspx</LinkUrl></Action><Description /><Date>2013-01-03T12:41:03</Date></Document><Document relevance="75816730" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"><Title>Test blogg - Länkar</Title><Action><LinkUrl size="0" fileExt="aspx">http://skvkfm-100-1:9899/sites/sitedirectory/UB_bloggtest/Lists/Lankar/AllItems.aspx</LinkUrl></Action><Description>I listan Länkar samlar du länkar till webbsidor som är intressanta eller användbara för gruppmedlemmarna.</Description><Date>2011-04-28T12:57:45</Date></Document><Document relevance="74951580" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"><Title>Test blogg - Kategorier</Title><Action><LinkUrl size="0" fileExt="aspx">http://skvkfm-100-1:9899/sites/sitedirectory/UB_bloggtest/Lists/Kategorier/AllCategories.aspx</LinkUrl></Action><Description>Använd listan Kategorier om du vill definiera kategorier för inlägg.</Description><Date>2011-04-28T12:57:46</Date></Document><Document relevance="74940626" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"><Title>Test blogg - Inlägg</Title><Action><LinkUrl size="0" fileExt="aspx">http://skvkfm-100-1:9899/sites/sitedirectory/UB_bloggtest/Lists/Anslag/AllPosts.aspx</LinkUrl></Action><Description>Använd listan Inlägg för inlägg i den här bloggen.</Description><Date>2012-09-20T17:48:27</Date></Document><Document relevance="73484562" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"><Title>Test blogg - Kommentarer</Title><Action><LinkUrl size="0" fileExt="aspx">http://skvkfm-100-1:9899/sites/sitedirectory/UB_bloggtest/Lists/Kommentarer/AllComments.aspx</LinkUrl></Action><Description>I listan Kommentarer lagras kommentarer som har gjorts i inlägg.</Description><Date>2012-09-20T17:48:27</Date></Document><Document relevance="68521602" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"><Title>Webbplatskatalogen</Title><Action><LinkUrl size="430688">http://skvkfm-100-1:9899/sites/sitedirectory</LinkUrl></Action><Description /><Date>2013-01-09T18:20:56</Date></Document><Document relevance="68517432" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"><Title>df</Title><Action><LinkUrl size="98487">http://skvkfm-100-1:9899/sites/df</LinkUrl></Action><Description>df</Description><Date>2013-01-09T18:20:38</Date></Document><Document relevance="66580222" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"><Title>Home - df</Title><Action><LinkUrl size="0" fileExt="aspx">http://skvkfm-100-1:9899/sites/df/default.aspx</LinkUrl></Action><Description /><Date>2013-01-09T18:23:24</Date></Document><Document relevance="65463796" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"><Title>df - How To Use This Library</Title><Action><LinkUrl size="73538" fileExt="aspx">http://skvkfm-100-1:9899/sites/df/SitePages/How To Use This Library.aspx</LinkUrl></Action><Description /><Date>2013-01-03T12:38:23</Date></Document></Results></Range><Status>SUCCESS</Status></Response></ResponsePacket>
```

**Note:** Make sure your web application has service application connection with Search Service application. A service application connection associates the service application to Web applications via membership in a service application connection group (also referred to as application proxy group).

Sample Search.asmx url that I used: `http://testserver-100-1:46812/_vti_bin/search.asmx`

Happy SharePointing!

Answer (score 1):

have a loook at your web.config:

change the following:

```
ClientCredentialType=Ntlm
```

to

```
clientCredentialType = windows
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762239/difference-between-clientcredentialtype-windows-and-ntlm

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608887/sharepoint-web-services-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authenti

**EDIT**

someone had a similar issue:

> The system admin only configured Kerberos for one web application. The
>   web part was querying the WCF service for a different web application
>   which only had NTLM configured.

[Why do I get a 401 error when calling a WCF service from a web part?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5467/why-do-i-get-a-401-error-when-calling-a-wcf-service-from-a-web-part)

this also leads me to belive that you must of missed a setting ;)

http://pankajsurti.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-anonymous-the-authentication-header-received-from-the-server-was-ntlm/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940703/not-authorized-for-search-asmx-web-service

**EDIT|**

add the following code to your code:

```
// ** We need to specify an identity (any identity) in order to get it past .net3.5 sp1
EndpointIdentity epi = EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("unknown");
EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(address),epi);

client = new DocumentConverterServiceClient(binding, epa);

client.Open();
```

[SharePoint search web service error (NTLM) when called from HttpHandler](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4734/sharepoint-search-web-service-error-ntlm-when-called-from-httphandler)

hope it helps :)

Comment: I've already specified credential type using this code: `binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;`

Comment: have you looked at your web.config to see the current security settings? also check that all webapplication settings are correct, i mean is kerbos only for one webapplication? check this out ;) http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5467/why-do-i-get-a-401-error-when-calling-a-wcf-service-from-a-web-part

Comment: Kerberos is using for all web applications.  Which security settings should I check?

Comment: just a side note before you check all this: have you checked permissions were not granted to "authenticated user" in any of the Sharepoint permission groups? you should add "authenticated user" to the Viewers group. I presume when you ran the code in the console app it was at an admin level and not the same user using the webpart?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/99920d1f-12f2-4e32-8501-f92ee0435ec0

Comment: Permissions are correct, please refer to my update.

Comment: ok iv done some digging and think its 100% todo with pernissions between kerbos and windows (a layer of crazy security) it looks like someone has the solution, checkout my edit

Comment: hi kia, did you manage to try my solution? it should only add a couple of lines of code to yours and it should work like a charm  :)

Answer (score 1):

In your Web application's web.config add following tag within  `<system.web>`,

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Comment: I've just check - authentication mode is Windows in web.config, also it has `<identity impersonate="true" />`

Comment: @Kai Is there any chance to view web.config of your web application as to figure out what's or where if anything is missing and also I think you figured out how to debug web services (using console app)